# StaticQuery 'data' is undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm a noob using gatsby and strapi. Trying to make a simple component that uses a graphql query.

```
import React from "react"
import {StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

export default ({data}) => (
    <StaticQuery
          query={graphql`
            query indQuery {
                allStrapiIndustry {
                    edges {
                      node {
                        title
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
          `}
          render={data.allStrapiIndustry.edges.map(document => (
            <header>
              <h1>{document.node.title}</h1>
            </header>
           ) )}
        />
    )
```

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/), the way you render the data is wrong. you need to pass a function (and not a value), like so:

```js
render={
  data => data.allStrapiIndustry.edges.map(document =>
  (
    <header>
      <h1>{document.node.title}</h1>
    </header>
  )
}
```